# make footer in new row in recycleview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have list with only three items , and i'm using GridLayout with two columns , so when calling it i found that rwo two has only one item , and the last is my footer , so i want to something add empty item or move my footer when my list has odd numbers to move new row

[image]

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,  int position) {

    if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
        loadChatMessages();
    }
private boolean isPositionFooter(int position) {
    return position == dish.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (isPositionFooter(position)) {
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dish.size() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own version of [`GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html) and add it to your layout manager by calling [`gridlayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(myLookup)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanSizeLookup(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)).

The description of `SpanSizeLookup` reads

> A helper class to provide the number of spans each item occupies.

So for every normal item you'd return `1` (column used) and in case of your footer you need to return `2` (or the amount of columns total) from `getSpanSize(int position)` and you're set.

This will signal the layout manager that it needs the whole row.